# Running total that changes with the slicers

Tags: powerbi

Fairly new to power bi. I have created a calculated column based on the index to calculate running total. However this fails when slicers are introduced. Also the  data set I have is not a date. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: can you share error message?

Comment: No error . Running total doesn’t respond to slicers. Numbers stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns are calculated at refresh time and stored.  Measures are recalculated based on the current filters and slicers.

So you need a [measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures), not a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle `slicers` try the following formula with the `ALLSELECTED` function. Even if your data is not based on dates still you should be able to calculate:

```
Running Total =
VAR CurrentIndex = MAX('Table'[Index])
VAR FilteredTable = FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Table'), 'Table'[Index] <= CurrentIndex)
RETURN
SUMX(FilteredTable, 'Table'[Value])
```

Comment: That's not a measure, as it assumes there is one value for Index, and so requires row scope to run.  You could try `var CurrentIndex = max('Table'[Index])`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yeah you are right, that's the calculated column formula, not the measure formula.  It can't change the slicer selection

Comment: I did try measure. Values are completely wrong .  My index is basically A - I .image001.png

Comment: can you share what you've done so far

Comment: Row_total running total =
CALCULATE(
    [Row_total running total in Attribute 2],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID]),
        ISONORAFTER('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID], MAX('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID]), DESC)
    )

Comment: can you change this line: `ISONORAFTER('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID],  MAX('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID]), DESC)` with the following and try again: `'Waterfall'[Attribute_ID] <= MAX('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID]`

Comment: updated lines: 

`Running Total = CALCULATE(
    [Row_total running total in Attribute 2],
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID]),
        'Waterfall'[Attribute_ID] <= MAX('Waterfall'[Attribute_ID])))`

Comment: image002.png . Doesn’t work